2D animated series involving four boys and a "sensei" type character who sends them to another world to fight
I'm trying to identify a 2D animated series from the mid 2000s onwards, I think?
From what I remember, there was a red-haired boy who transferred to a new city with his mum and it was all futuristic-ish. He made friends with a blue-haired boy and they had a "sensei" type character old man who would send them to another world to fight. Not sure if there were robots they fought in.
Later on, they gained two more members, those being a short, angry green-haired guy and a taller yellow-haired guy who was very chill.

You could improve this question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, how did he get to the other world? How old was the boy? What was his name? What/how did he fight? Was there a villain? Was there an end-goal they were trying to achieve? Was the fight for an actual prize or just a league of some description? Was this aimed at children or adults (e.g. with sex/drugs/violence, etc)?

Is this Tenkai Knights (2013–2014)...?
From MyAnimeList:

Tenkai Knights is an original Canadian-Japanese anime series that officially aired in Cartoon Network in the United States on August 24, 2013 and in Canada on Teletoon on September 28, 2013. The anime premiered a year after in Japan on TV Tokyo. The purpose of the anime's creation was the promotion of Spin Master's line of Ionix construction bricks. Spin Master is a Canadian toy and entertainment company which started producing and promoting The Tenkai Knights toy line along with a new Pokémon line. The anime was adapted into a video game for Nintendo 3DS.


The two main characters in the first episode are Guren Nash, a boy with red hair, and Ceylan Jones, a boy with blue hair. Guren has just moved to Benham City with his father, and after his first day at his new school, he and Ceylan go to a shopping mall together and wander into a mysterious antique shop, where they find a pair of Lego-like bricks which can be transformed into mini-robot figures. The shop owner, Mr. White, lets the boys keep the toys as a gift, and later that night, they have a dream about a battle between two robot-like beings.
The next day, they go back to the shop, but Mr. White is nowhere to be found, so they wander downstairs to the basement, where they discover a device that transports them to a distant planet named Quarton. This planet is home to two warring races of robot-like beings, like the ones they saw in their dreams; the benevolent Corekai and the malevolent Corrupted, led by Vilius. On this planet, the boys inhabit the robot-like forms of Bravenwolf and Tributon, two of the legendary Tenkai Knights who aided the Corekai against the Corrupted in the past.
In the second episode, the boys meet two more Tenkai Knights, Valorn and Lydendor, who also turn out to be boys from Earth named Toxsa Dalton and Chooki Mason, respectively; Toxsa has green hair while Chooki has yellow hair.




An excellent find (and a terrible show) :-)
